# Accessing MERRA data using Python 3

Tags: python-3.x

I have been trying to access MERRA weather station data from the NASA powered website (https://disc.sci.gsfc.nasa.gov/). I have used various snippets of code that I found on stackoverflow.com, but I am met with the following errors. The website requires me to login and I have implemented this using the following codes-

```
dataset_url = 'link to data'  
session = setup_session('username'.encode('utf-8'), 'password'.encode('utf-8'), check_url=dataset_url)  
dataset_2 = open_url(dataset_url, session = session)
```

In the above case, the error is "UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x8b in position 1: invalid start byte". Alternately, I have also tried

```
dataset_2 = urllib.request.urlopen(dataset_url)
```

which returns "HTTPError : Unauthorized."

```
request = urllib.request.Request('link to data')    
base64string = base64.b64encode('%s:%s' % (username.encode('utf-8'), password.encode('utf-8'))  
request.add_header("Authorization", "Basic %s" % base64string)     
result = urllib.urlopen(request)
```

In the above case, the error is "request.add_header("Authorization", "Basic %s" % base64string)
SyntaxError: invalid syntax" with the syntax error pointer pointing to the function *request*.

```
password_mgr = urllib.request.HTTPPasswordMgrWithDefaultRealm()
top_level_url = 'https://disc.sci.gsfc.nasa.gov/'
password_mgr.add_password(None, top_level_url, 'username', 'password')
handler = urllib.request.HTTPBasicAuthHandler(password_mgr)
opener = urllib.request.build_opener(handler)
opener.open('link to data')
urllib.request.install_opener(opener)
```

In the above case, the error is "HTTPError : Unauthorized."

```
theurl = 'link to data'
username = 'username'
password = 'password'
passman = urllib.request.HTTPPasswordMgrWithDefaultRealm()
passman.add_password(None, theurl, username, password)
authhandler = urllib.request.HTTPBasicAuthHandler(passman)
opener = urllib.request.build_opener(authhandler)
urllib.request.install_opener(opener)
pagehandle = urllib.request.urlopen(theurl)
```

In the above case, the error is "HTTPError : Unauthorized." The method is quite similar to the previous case.

```
url='link to data'
username = 'username'
password = 'password'
def credentials(url, username, password):
    p = urllib.request.HTTPPasswordMgrWithDefaultRealm()
    p.add_password(None, url, username, password)
    handler = urllib.request.HTTPBasicAuthHandler(p)
    opener = urllib.request.build_opener(handler)
    urllib.request.install_opener(opener)
credentials(url, username, password)
rest_api = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
latest_build_info = rest_api.read()
latest_build_info = latest_build_info.decode('UTF-8')
credentials(url, username, password)
urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, downloaded_file)
```

In the above case, the error is "HTTPError : Unauthorized."

```
response = requests.get('link to data',verify=True, auth=('username'.encode('UTF-8'), 'password'.encode('UTF-8')))
print(response.text)
```

In the above case, the error is "HTTP Basic: Access denied."

The 'link to data' looks like 'https://website/path/filename.extension'. The type of files which I am trying to access are generally NetCDF or HDF. All required libraries have been imported properly.
I have been stuck with this for weeks now. Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Hi ... did you figure this out.   I am trying to do same.